# Passing parameter back from JSP in a portlet app

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, liferay

In my `Liferay 6` app I'm able to pass parameter from java to jsp via:

`final PortletRequestDispatcher rd = getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher("view");
request.setAttribute("description", "some description");
rd.include(request, response);`

Then I want user to change the description and pass it back to back-end:

`<form method="POST" action="${addItem}">
        <input name="description"
               type="text"
               value="${description}"/>
        <button  type="submit">UPDATE</button>
    </form>`

Nevertheless when I call then `System.out.println("request.getAttribute("description"));` , I'm getting `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youre passing in the parameter but checking the request attribute (assuming that the outer quotes are a question typo). Based on the information you provided, the initial request attribute was only available in the `JSP` but not any subsequent servlet. Try

```
System.out.println(request.getParameter("description"));
```

Comment: Oh...you're completly right! Such a stupid mistake! :) ...I've spent 4 hours seeking for a mistake in the rest of the code :)